# How can I Drop and Drag a pin on a map in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, mapkit, mkannotation, mkpinannotationview

Hope someone can help, I'm trying to implement dropping one single Pin on a mapView. But I want the pin to be able to be dragged around and and dropped and for this annotation to be separate from the annotation for the user's location. Whilst the below code works, it creates duplicate pins for a user's touch and the pins can not be dragged around:

```
- (void)dropPinFromPress:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    // Add Pin from User's Touch
    if (recognizer.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        return;
    }

    // convert touched position to map coordinate
    CGPoint userTouch = [recognizer locationInView:self.mapView];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D mapPoint = [self.mapView convertPoint:userTouch toCoordinateFromView:self.mapView];

    // Add Pin from user's touch
    Annotation *pin = [[Annotation alloc]initWithLocation:mapPoint];
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:pin];    
}
```

Comment: you got your solution ??

Answer (score 0):

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation
{
    MKAnnotationView *a = [ [ MKAnnotationView alloc ] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"currentloc"];
    //  a.title = @"test";
    if ( a == nil )
        a = [ [ MKAnnotationView alloc ] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier: @"currentloc" ];

    NSLog(@"%f",a.annotation.coordinate.latitude);
    NSLog(@"%f",a.annotation.coordinate.longitude);

    CLLocation* currentLocationMap = [[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:a.annotation.coordinate.latitude longitude:a.annotation.coordinate.longitude] autorelease];
    [self coordinatesToDMS:currentLocationMap];


    MKPinAnnotationView *annView=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:a reuseIdentifier:@"currentloc"];
    if(a.annotation.coordinate.longitude == mapView.userLocation.coordinate.longitude ||  a.annotation.coordinate.latitude == mapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude  )
    {
        if ([annotation isKindOfClass:MKUserLocation.class])
        {
            //user location view is being requested,
            //return nil so it uses the default which is a blue dot...
            return nil;
        }       
        //a.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"userlocation.png"];
        //a.pinColor=[UIColor redColor];
    }
    else 
    {

        // annView.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"map-pin.png"];
        //PinFirst=FALSE;
        //annView.pinColor = [UIColor redColor];
        // annView.annotation=annotation;
    }

    annView.animatesDrop = YES;
    annView.draggable = YES;

    annView.canShowCallout = YES;

    return annView;
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"map Drag");
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view didChangeDragState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)newState
fromOldState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)oldState;
{
    NSLog(@"pin Drag");

    if (newState == MKAnnotationViewDragStateEnding)
    {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D droppedAt = view.annotation.coordinate;
        NSLog(@"Pin dropped at %f,%f", droppedAt.latitude, droppedAt.longitude);

        CLLocation* draglocation = [[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:droppedAt.latitude longitude:droppedAt.longitude] autorelease];



    }
}
```